# working with .obj - fixing mesh

Tags: mesh, obj

I need good renders of some models that i have as .obj files. However, I have a feeling that they have very messed up meshes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Am I correct? As when I try to "shade smooth" it looks awful (above).
Even worse happens with subdivision surface. If I'm right with saying that the mesh is the problem here, is there any way to fix it?

If not - second option - I would be happy to model everything from scratch (less detailed), using the .obj as reference, and I'm wondering what is the best way to approach it. If i work with these two objects (my model + the .obj as reference), it gets really difficult to see what is what:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried shade smooth with autosmooth enabled? Most hard surface meshes will look pretty bad with just AS by itself.

Comment: Object Data Properties > Clear custom Normal data

Comment: thanks, tried that and it help a little bit, but still not enough, it looks like I will end up creating the models from scratch. Any advice how to use these .obj as reference?

Comment: There is a Remesh modifier that sometimes works for me.  You can then Apply it if you want to work further with the new mesh.